# Getting CPU utilization information

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

How could I get the CPU utilization with time info of a process in linux? Basically I want to let my application run overnight. At the same time, I would like to monitor the CPU utilization during the period the application is run.

I tried top | grep appName >& log, it does not seem to return me anything in the log. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**vmstat** and **iostat** can both give you periodic information of this nature; I would suggest either setting up the number of times manually, or putting a single poll into a cron job, and then redirecting the output to a file:

```
vmstat 20 4230 >> cpu_log_file
```

This would give you a snapshot of usage every 20 seconds for 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

install sysstat package and run sar

```
nohup sar -o output.file 12 8 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

use the top or watch command

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH  #WQ  #PORT #MREG RPRVT  RSHRD  RSIZE  VPRVT  VSIZE  PGRP  PPID  STATE    UID  FAULTS    COW    MSGSENT    MSGRECV    SYSBSD    SYSMACH   CSW       PAGEINS USER
10764  top          8.4  00:01.04 1/1  0    24    33    2000K  244K   2576K  17M    2378M      10764 10719 running  0    9908+     54     564790+    282365+    3381+     283412+   838+          27      root
10763  taskgated    0.0  00:00.00 2    0    25    27    432K   244K   1004K  27M    2387M  10763 1     sleeping 0    376       60     140        60         160       109       11        0       root
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a program that invokes your process and then calls getrusage(2) and reports statistics for its children.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the time used by your program with `top` while it is running.

Alternatively, you can launch your application with the `time` command, which will print the total amount of CPU time used by your program at the end of its execution. Just type `time ./my_app` instead of just `./my_app`

For more info, `man 1 time`